# asp.net identity CurrentPrincipal.Identity does not contain custom claim

Tags: claims-based-identity, asp.net-identity-2

So during login I create claims. However I seem to be losing my custom claim (UserData). Below is my code for creating the claims:

```
// create required claims
                claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, UserContext.UserId.ToString()));
                claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, UserContext.Email));

                // custom – my serialized UserContext object
                claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.UserData, UserContext.Serialize(UserContext)));

                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

                AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent, AllowRefresh = true }, identity);
```

Checking the ClaimsIdentity (identity) I see:

```
{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier: 12
{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name: test@test.com}
{http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/userdata: Something}
```

So while debuging I get the current principal immediately after:

```
var identity1 = (ClaimsPrincipal)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
```

Now in identity1 I only see the following:

```
{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier: 12}
{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name: test@test.com}
{http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider: ASP.NET Identity}
{http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role: Role1}
```

my custom UserData claim is gone.

**Update:**
just wanted to add that my AuthenticationManager is defined as:

```
HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
```

**Update:**
I have resolved this issue. In my PasswordSignIn method I had accidentally carried over the ExtneralCookie authentication type instead of using the ApplicationCookie:

```
AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExtenralCookie);
```

to

```
AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try by reading ClaimsIdentity from current thread like,

```
/// <summary>
        /// Gets authenticated identity
        /// </summary>
        private static ClaimsIdentity identity
        {
            get
            {
                return (ClaimsIdentity)Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity;
            }
        }
```

And read the claim by

```
/// <summary>
        /// gets authenticated UserId
        /// </summary>
        public static int UserId
        {
            get
            {
                return Convert.ToInt32(identity.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault());
            }
        }
```

you have to get UserDetail type instance so , need to deserialize the claim value.

Comment: Sorry the problem isn't reading the claims. The problem is the custom claim is missing. my other claims data is in there and I can read them just fine.

Comment: Try to get claimidentity instead claim principle

Comment: It doesn't matter which one I get the custom claim is missing.

Comment: Have you find any solution

Comment: I have not at this time. I'm sure it is some setting that we are missing as we have developed several other projects using similar authentication method. I'm actually working with Microsoft on the issue and will post an update once it gets resolved.